# How can configure or change eth1 to eth0 on Docker Container

Tags: linux, docker, networking, centos, network-programming

I have installed docker on centos 7 server. I have created a custom bridge and attached a docker container. Now I have two ethernet connections when I execute `ifconfig` command with:

- local network on `eth0` and
- one which is custom network on `eth1`.

I want to set custom network on `eth0` and local network on `eth1`. I tried but weren't able to do so into docker container. Please help.

I am awaiting for your prompt reply.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww What is the problem to you if I am asking docker related question at here ? I am also programmer and doing devops related task as well. I figure it out the solution and implemented in my project.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I configure or change...

You can't. Better think of it this way: your `container` is just a process. Kill it and spin up a new one with the correct configuration.

### An idea / example:

create your custom bridge:

```
$ docker network create test_net
c5e92fff4e386bab692f849d148509cdb9ae0e70307e0bf8426e62352c56368d
```

and at the execution of `docker run` attach your container to this bridge (`172.18.0.X`):

```
$ docker run -it --network=test_net alpine
...
```

then, connect the container to the default bridge (`172.17.0.X`)

```
$ docker network connect bridge <your_container_name>
```

Let's see what we've got:

```
$ docker container exec -it <your_container_name> sh
/ # ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:AC:12:00:02  
          inet addr:172.18.0.2  Bcast:172.18.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:54 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:6950 (6.7 KiB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:AC:11:00:02  
          inet addr:172.17.0.2  Bcast:172.17.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:50 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:6558 (6.4 KiB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Comment: I have created custom network with my static ip  and add into container creating time like this.  docker run -it --net cusotm_network --ip 123.78.67.4 and this is set on eth0 but when I added new bridge network then it will go on eth1 so how can I stay static on eth0 please help me...

Comment: @JainHemant did you figure out how to achieve this? I'm in the same situation

Comment: @TadasTamosauskas yes I have figure it out let me know what is the issue you are facing.......

Comment: I've ended up using ansible's `purge_networks` option, that got rid of the default eth0 for me, so the newly configured one became eth0.